# Outlook VSTO - Adding file path/hyperlink to MailItem WordEditor from Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, mailitem

I am having following problem.  I have a window that opens and allows me to select some files.
Then I can right-click on that window and choose to attach paths of selected files to a new mail dialog.

The workflow is like this:

1. I open my windows and select couple of files
2. Right-click, choose to add selected files paths to MailItem
3. Logic will check if there is an `ActiveInspector`

   3.1. If there is one, I get its `CurrentItem as MailItem` (so, new mail dialog exists and does not need to be created)

   3.2. If there is none, I call `CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.OLItemType.olMailItem)` to create
       new mail dialog and then I call `MailItem.Display(false)` to display
       the mail item dialog
4. Next I loop through list of selected files paths and add them to the new mail dialog.  This works great.

**PROBLEM** If I open my window for the 2nd time to select more files and add their paths to the same mail dialog I opened earlier, they are not added.

Here is the code:

```
public void AddFilePaths(List<string> paths)
{
    if (paths.Count > 0)
    {
        var inspector = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
        MailItem mi = null;
        bool newMailItem = false;

        if (inspector != null)
        {
            // If new mail dialog is already open, just get it.
            // This is called on my 2nd attempt to add paths to new mail.
            // This MailItem is the same one created on 1st call in below
            // else block.  I confirmed that by adding some dummy email
            // Body in below else block, then checking for it here on 
            // 2nd call.  I think this proves that correct 
            // Inspector/MailItem is returned here.
            mi = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as MailItem;
        }
        else
        {
            // create new mail dialog and display it
            // this is called on my 1st call to add paths to new mail
            mi = MyAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mi.Body = "Dummy email body"; 
            newMailItem = true;
        }

        if (newMailItem)
        {
            mi.Display();
            inspector = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
        }

        if (inspector != null)
        {
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                AddPathToActiveInspector(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above calls this method to add path to the current `ActiveInspector` `WordEditor`:

```
public void AddPathToActiveInspector(string path)
{
    var inspector = MyAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
    dynamic we = inspector.WordEditor;
    dynamic word = we.Application;
    const string nl = "\n";

    // I have noticed that if I am debugging, this line will throw error
    // "COMException was unhandled by user code", "An exception of type
    // System.Runtime.Interop.Services.COMException occurred in 
    // System.Dynamic.dll but was not handled by user code:
    // Message: This command is not available
    // InnerException: null
    // I have also seen following error on 2nd attempt: "The TypeText    
    // method or property is not available because the document is
    // locked for editing."
    word.Selection.TypeText(nl);

    string address = path;
    string subAddress = "";
    string screenTip = "";
    string displayText = path; 
    word.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(word.Selection.Range, ref address, ref subAddress, ref screenTip, ref displayText);
    word.Selection.TypeText(" "); 
}
```

Comment: So what happens if you step through your code? Does it actually run? Are you sure there is only one Inspector? What do you do with inline replies

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, please see my updated question.  I have traced the code and I get correct inspector/MailItem which I confirmed by adding dummy MailItem.Body message when MailItem is created (on 1st call), then checking Body for that text on 2nd call.  I added that to my code comment above.  I have also found that an COMException is thrown but only while debugging (???).  I added comment in my code for that, too.  In my Replies and forwards section (inline replies), nothing is checked and I'm including original message text (if that is what you meant with inline replies.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply create a new email message each time you are adding your paths to avoid the possibility of adding paths to a wrong email message which could happen if you have opened multiple emails.

1. Add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to your project
2. Add using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` on top of your class file

Here is the code:

```
public void AddFilePaths(List<string> paths)
{
    if (paths.Count > 0)
    {
        MailItem  mi = ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mi.Display();
        if (mi!= null)
        {
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                AddPathsToNewEmailMessage(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above calls this method to add the path to the new email message `WordEditor`:

```
public void AddPathsToNewEmailMessage(string path)
{
    object link = url;
    object result = "url";
    object missing = Type.Missing;
    string nl = "\n";

    var inspector = ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
    MailItem currMessage = inspector.CurrentItem;
    Word.Document doc = currMessage.GetInspector.WordEditor;
    Word.Selection sel = doc.Windows[1].Selection;
    doc.Hyperlinks.Add(sel.Range, ref result, ref missing, ref missing, ref link, ref missing);
    sel.EndKey(Word.WdUnits.wdLine);
    sel.InsertAfter(nl);
    sel.MoveDown(Word.WdUnits.wdLine);
}
```